# Is there a single word for "towards the equator"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for the direction towards the equator wherever you happen to be standing?

Suppose, you wanted to convey the following message:

> If you are in the Southern hemisphere, orient yourself facing North; if you are in the Northern hemisphere, orient yourself facing South.

The message appears clumsy. Is there a single word that means "towards the equator"?

Comment: antipoleward is a word....in molecular biology.

Comment: Anything wrong with "towards the equator"?

Comment: "but it feels clumsy". Why? That's pretty common, or perhaps "orient yourself northward".

Comment: @ralph.m If you specify a single cardinal direction, it's only right for one half of the earth. :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just reword the whole sentence as "Face the equator."?

Comment: @200_success Yes, but my example is a toy example. There is a context in technical writing where it becomes very clumsy not to have a single word meaning "the direction of the equator". Think how awful it would be if you couldn't use the direction "north" but had to say "in the direction of the axis the earth spins around located in the Arctic" or something silly. :-)

Comment: Can you give a real example then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is the single word ***equatorward*** but it is mainly used in geographical context.

> toward or near the equator
>
> *currents flowing equatorward, equatorward winds*
>
> [*MW*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equatorward)

Comment: Look at that. A real word that means *exactly* what I asked. Funny how my Googling didn't turn that one up. Thanks Ermanen!

Comment: Equatorbound I guess could work too. Does that need a hyphen?

Answer (score 4):

In conventional speech, I think most fluent English speakers would say "towards the equator". If geographers or some other profession of a single word for this, I don't think it's in common use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**equator-facing**".

Thus, your example may be simplified as follows:

> Wherever you happen to be standing, stand **equator-facing**.

Comment: That's just a clumsier way of saying "facing the equator."

Answer (score 0):

What about the word "**adequatorial**"? That is, "ad-" +"equatorial." Although "**equatorward**" is just the word for it, as everyone seems to agree, I have a personal distaste for a Latin word (or Greek, etc.) with an English suffix, i.e. "-ward." Purely an aesthetic issue for me. Does this seem like a usable word? I'm coining it, as far as I know.